# "Greater than" cost benefit analysis

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I am choosing an advertising method, one that costs $7.84$ per $1000$ people who view my advertisement or $0.51$ per person who clicks my advertisement, what percent of people would have to click my advertisement in method $1$ for it to be more cost effective than method $2$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You are expected to assume that all clicks are equally valuable to you.  If you get one click per $0.51$ in the second case, how many views can you buy for $0.51$ in the first.  Then one of those people needs to click.

Comment: is it 1.54%?      (7.84/1000)/.51

Comment: I can buy 65.06 views for the price of 1 click

Comment: Yes, that is right.